# Distinguish between conversion failure and validation failure in o:viewParamValidationFailed

Tags: validation, jsf, omnifaces

I am using the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) `<o:viewParam>` taghandler in my current project. I like it, it's great. And even greater is the  [`<o:viewParamValidationFailed>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/viewParamValidationFailed). Now, we are able to send an error if validation or conversion fails. But I wonder, whether it is possible to distinguish between conversion failure and validation failure.

Let's say we want to send a *Bad Request* if the given view param in malformed and can not be converted; for that matter send a *Not Found* if conversion succeeded, but the object could not be found in the database; and send a *Forbidden* if the successfully fetched object should not be accessed by the user.

Does anybody know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible to distinguish between a `ConverterException` and `ValidatorException` when you've only `UIInput#isValid()` at hands. Theoretically, you could check and test the faces message to see if it represents a conversion or validation error, but this is not a robust approach, certainly not when it's localized.

On the other hand, it's possible to declare multiple view parameters on the same parameter name. You do not necessarily need to specify a `value` to set it as model value.

Here's an example based on your description, note that the model value is only set on the last one:

```
<o:viewParam name="foo">
    <f:converter converterId="yourFooConverter" />
    <o:viewParamValidationFailed sendError="400" />
</o:viewParam>
<o:viewParam name="foo">
    <f:converter converterId="yourFooConverter" />
    <f:validateRequired />
    <o:viewParamValidationFailed sendError="404" />
</o:viewParam>
<o:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:converter converterId="yourFooConverter" />
    <f:validateRequired />
    <f:validator validatorId="yourRestrictedAccessValidator" />
    <o:viewParamValidationFailed sendError="403" />
</o:viewParam>
```

To avoid the expensive job of calling the DB on every conversion, let the `YourFooConverter` implementation store the converted value as a custom attribute of the `FacesContext` and then check it on every pass.

Comment: It works. Great job. I already tried this approach, but missed to specify the converter in each viewParam taghandler.

Comment: I just wrote this optimization (store the converted value as a custom attribute), but apparently the given `UIComponent` is the `o:viewParam` of each pass and therefore not consistent. I simply add the value to the given `FacesContext` which works fine in all tests. Is there any reason not to do so?